# Creating a view in MySQL that needs to update itself weekly

Tags: mysql, sql, view, workbench

I'm trying to create views in MySQL Workbench which would serve me to extract weekly reports, that covers the period between Monday and Sunday.

I don't know how to write it dynamically so that the date gets updated by itself. 
This is the query i wrote:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), count(distinct(playerId)) FROM innodb.player_spin 
WHERE date between 1512950400 and 1513555199
GROUP BY from_unixtime(date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually work in T-SQL, so I cannot confirm that this works by running it.

Use the [Weekday function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp) and some [date math](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

```
SELECT from_unixtime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), count(distinct(playerId)) FROM 
innodb.player_spin 
where date between (Date_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) and (Date_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE() +7) DAY)
group by from_unixtime(date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's not working for MySQL, but thanks a lot for your tips, i am looking into weekday function and date math meanwhile.